# No extension method with windows forms

Tags: c#

The problem is in

```
num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text);
```

of `bankAccount()`

I am attempting to make it where you can type any decimal into the withBox textbox and when you click the button it will give you the amount in the `aMtBox`. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Is gives me this error, but I do not know why?

What I am wanting, is for num1 to equal whatever I type into my withBox. That is my end goal.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BankAccount a = new BankAccount();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        decimal iBa = 300.00m;
        this.aMtBox.Text = iBa.ToString();
    }
    private void dep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal num1 = 0.00m;
            decimal iBa = 300.00m;
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.depBox.Text);
            decimal total = num1 + iBa;
            this.aMtBox.Text = total.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "Oops, this isn't good!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    public void withdrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.aMtBox.Text = a.Balance.ToString();
    }

    public class BankAccount
    {
        decimal balance;
        decimal iBa;
        decimal num1;

        public decimal Balance
        {
            get { return balance; }
        }
        public decimal IBa
        {
            get { return iBa; }
        }
        public decimal Num1
        {
            get { return num1; }
        }

        public BankAccount()
        {
            iBa = 300.00m;
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text);
            balance = iBa - num1;
        }
    }

    private void withBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error message was.  Also, how many times are you going to keep pasting the same code and asking questions about it?  At some point, you might want to consider picking up a book or finding a tutor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would love a tutor, but I have a crappy book that I paid 30 bucks for. I am trying to learn. Learned more off google and youtube videos than my book. Sorry for keep prying at a question but I want to figure it out so I understand it. Only way I know to go at it.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the current instance of the class. `this` in your `BankAccount` constructor refers to the `BankAccount`.. not the `Form`. Therefore, you cannot access `withBox` from within `BankAccount`.

What you need to do.. is pass the textbox instance in. Somewhat like this:

```
public class BankAccount {
    public BankAccount(TextBox withBox) { // Pass it in
        iBa = 300.00m;
        num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(withBox.Text);
        balance = iBa - num1;
    }
    // ...the rest of the class
}
```

Then, in your `Form`.. create your `BankAccount` like this:

```
BankAccount a = new BankAccount(withBox);
```

Comment: You beat me to it by literally 1 second :).

Answer (score 0):

`withBox` is not a member of the class `BankAccount` but you're trying to access it as such.  I assume `withBox` is a member of class `Form1`

```
    public BankAccount()
    {
        iBa = 300.00m;
        // this.withBox is no good, no such property/member variable exists
        num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text);
        balance = iBa - num1;
    }
```

Comment: Essentially yes, that is what I read, but I cant declare my BankAccount  class to consist of everything else so I do not know what to do.

Comment: Pass withBox.Text into the constructor

Comment: could I declare BankAccount a part of public partial class Form1 : Form

Comment: That wouldn't work for you either since you only create an instance of `BankAccount` during member initialization of `Form1`, so as far as that one instance of `BankAccount` is concerned, `withBox.Text`'s value never changes